# Should we encourage or discourage social & community focused questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-scope, specific-question

[As a substrate dev, what are the most exciting podcasts you're listening to right now?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/as-a-substrate-dev-what-are-the-most-exciting-podcasts-youre-listening-to-righ/) is an illustrative example of such a post. This is opinion based, and at least as it stands now, as I see it, not really covered in what kind of posts we want to encourage on our SE.

What do you think is in bounds and out of bounds for social posts here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, these sorts of questions are discouraged on the *main* site - but they can be a good avenue for community building and discussion on the meta site or in chat.

It's important to remember that the hope is that questions and answers on this site be somewhat timeless. While we know that technology changes and solutions can morph as things change, questions like this are inherently going to cease being useful - and soon.

What podcast I'm listening to now will be useless to people in 2-5 years when those podcasts are no longer around!

Also, the tags mentioned in [your answer](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/59) are what we refer to as "meta tags" - tags that classify the type of question rather than being related to the subject of the question itself. These sorts of tags (e.g. "beginner" or "best-practices") are generally strongly discouraged and have been since early days.

[Here's a blog post written by Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) called "The Death of Meta Tags" and the main point of the post:

> #### From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.
>
> ##### How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> - If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> - If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

So, while these are "discouraged" and you can opt to ignore this, it's at least worth mentioning that we've gone down this path before on other sites and it's kinda something we find doesn't generally work well.

---

So, while we won't explicitly prohibit y'all from having these questions, I'm going to at least discourage it.

- Give your site room to grow and be a truly objective site.
- Avoid questions that won't be useful in a few years.
- If you want to link to good resources like blogs or podcasts, do it on meta.

Comment: That is a good point, it is a good opportunity to engage the community here, in meta! And it will most likely show up in "Featured on Meta" on Q&A site.

Comment: @Bruno and, as a mod, you can add the featured tag to any post you wish to appear in the bulletin on the main site, so you can draw attention to the questions if you wish.

Comment: Wow that is good to know and will come in useful for community building. Thanks for the tip @Catija!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I am biased to allow for this kind of post, with tags that explicitly help filter based on wanting to see them or not. But I also realize this introduces extra friction to seeing the "meat" of what this site is about: technical questions about Substrate and Polkadot specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example question given (and the answers that were provided) is resourceful to the audience and in-line with the scope of this site. However, I do think these types of questions can easily become opinionated depending on how it is worded, framed, or answered.

I think we should allow for these types of questions on a case-by-case basis and perhaps as a steward for good "social/community" questions create a few ourselves to serve as a template for the rest of the community that we can later reference as a good example of how to ask such a question.

Comment: Good for meta! We can use this sub site to encourage this, and redirect people from the main site